# How to convert std::vector<uint8_t> to std::basic_string<std:::byte> for usage with pqxx

Tags: c++

I am upgrading an application from using libpqxx `7.1.2` to `7.3.1` and one of the things that have changed in the meantime is that `pqxx::binarystring` has been deprecated in favour of `std::basic_string<std::byte>`.
My issue is that I use `std::vector<uint8_t>` in C++ to represent a SHA-1 hash, which I then need to store in Postgress as BYTEA. So now I need to find a way to convert `std::vector<uint8_t>` to `std::basic_string<std::byte>` and back.
But I have been unable to find a way to get from vector -> string.

I have been looking at the constructor for `std::basic_string<T>` and simply cannot figure out how to do it.
Amongst other ways to construct `std::basic_strig<T>` I have tried this, but all give compiler errors `error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::basic_string<std::byte>'`.
But when I look at the documentation, I thought the different options I have tried should be legal. So how do I achieve this?

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> data = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::basic_string<std::byte> a(std::begin(data), std::end(data));
    std::basic_string<std::byte> b((char*)data.data(), data.size()); 
}
```

Comment: What about `std::basic_string<std::byte> b(reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(data.data()), data.size());` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is strange that they have chosen a `basic_string` instead of a `vector` for this, but this works:

```
std::basic_string<std::byte> a(
    static_cast<const std::byte *>(static_cast<const void *>(data.data())),
    data.size()
);
```

It should be fine because `uint8_t` is trivially copyable and `std::byte` pointers can alias others.

Comment: Yeah I was surprised too. But the reason is down `libpq` using strings here I think